# Last chance for this question - can someone explain what is wrong with my first question?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday after 5+ years of membership I asked my [first question here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/422255/169548). Within 16 hours it received 2 negative votes and 60-something views. I don't want to reiterate all that philology that's been around for ages about voting and negativity. Not because that's not the problem but because we've all heard them.

Though I can't pretend that there is not a problem here! **A negative vote without some constructive feedback is digital booing.** Where I come from, we call this κακοήθεια (kakoítheia) which translates to bad [ethos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethos). I am a *software engineer* and **I have a degree on it.** As a result I was hoping that site is for *exchanging ideas* with like minded people.

So I would like to humbly ask the remaining of the community of this site to have a look at my lousy question and tell me what is wrong with it -if there is any. Some of us (me included for those that can't see the obvious) use our real names to post and as a result **we take full responsibility of what we write** and as such we don't want B/S to be associated to our name.

Comment: @donwvoter Don't forget to downvote without commenting the actual question! Your feedback is always appreciated and makes that community better!

Comment: I didn't vote (yet), but see: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325417/165773)

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personal - IMHO this is a long-standing community problem, not yours. See my [meta-answer here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9160), or my [meta question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8884/can-we-improve-our-style-of-self-moderation-for-not-too-bad-questions).

Comment: @gnat first thanks for taking the time to read and comment (not as obvious as one might think). I don't care about your vote or anyone's vote for that matter, I care about 1. being useful (but as such I can't be pleasant at the same time) and 2. improve myself. Regarding the link yes I know and that's why I wrote my 3rd sentence. I can debunk each and every of the bullets but that's not the right place. If nobody tells you "hey mate you are doing xyz wrong" how the hell someone can achieve #2? And if voting is abused #1 is also lost.

Comment: @DocBrown Doc thanks for taking the time to read and comment. I'm sorry but I feel it personal. I write with my full name. That might give me or even worse cost me a job tomorrow. Since that thread might be my the last activity in softwareengineering SE, I want to thank you for your contribution. I've read many good answers from you and I consider your contribution to this site priceless.

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis: I am pretty sure there is no job at stake for you because you asked a question here on Softwareengineering.SE which currently got 4 upvotes (as well as two downvotes from community members who obviously have a communication problem).

Comment: @DocBrown Just mentioning the consequences of using one's real name. That's all, my comment is not for this case per se. :)

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis: honestly, if you fear your public actions and responses on this site might interfere with your job, I am sure complaining loud and harshly about getting some virtual minus points is not the best course of action. You will probably be better off to disconnect your SE account from SE.SE and create a new anonymous one.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer is in [Doc's first linked answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9160):

> **It has become almost impossible to ask a question without getting one or two downvotes at least.**

Frankly, I didn't know that. If I did, I wouldn't be "complaining loud and harshly about getting some virtual minus points". And since we are talking about that, I am disappointed to see that people (well at least one) perceived my message as such. I am complaining loud and harshly about the *attitude*, not about "fake internet points" as very aptly another member once wrote. I want the question to have a chance to be answered and starting with a -2 "just because" isn't the best omen. Doc gave the above answer to another member's question suggesting that

> Negatively scored questions should be more aggressively hidden from the homepage

There it is, I am right to be unpleasant. Unfortunately. Anyway, now I know. Thanks to everyone taking the time to read and give constructive feedback.